# Sum arrays in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the result from database.

```
Array
(
    [0] = stdClass Object
    (
        [name] = First
        [sum] = 3,8,...
    )

    [1] = stdClass Object
    (
        [name] = Second
        [sum] = -1,0,...
    )

    [2] = stdClass Object
    (
        [name] = Third
        [sum] = 2,-1...
    )

)
```

So now I need to sum all in column **"sum"**.

I need to get result like

```
$final = (4, 7,...);
```

I have transformed **sum** to array throw **explode()** and then tried with foreach

for example

```
foreach ($result as $k=>$subArray) {
   $arrayNumbers = explode(",",$subArray->sum);

    foreach ($arrayNumbers as $key => $value) {
     $sumArray[] = $value];
     $stepToSum2[] = array_sum($sumArray);

  }
  unset($arrayNumb);
}
```

Not sure that my example working because I'm already stuck with commented code.

Anyway, I with some manipulations I can get or sum right for the first numbers (5) or the sum of my array (11).

The same result with this

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($var) {
  return $var['sum'];
}, $myResultArray));
```

I have searched for the answer but most of the answers only for two arrays, but in same tables, I have more than 5 arrays, so I can't figure out how to implement this.

Comment: Do you have always the same structure for the sum attribute in your database?

Comment: number 1, number 2 ?

Comment: or there can be x numbers per row

Comment: There are more than 100 numbers for each one separated by  comma, but always with the same number. The structure is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) is good for reducing an array to a single value as you're doing here. It takes an array and a function that updates a "carry" value for each item in your array.

```
$result = array_reduce($your_array, function($carry, $item) {
    foreach (explode(',', $item->sum) as $key => $value) {
        $carry[$key] = $value + (isset($carry[$key]) ? $carry[$key] : 0);
        // (OR $carry[$key] = $value + ($carry[$key] ?? 0); in PHP 7)
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Comment: Is it only for two numbers in SUM?

Comment: Because my sum looks like [sum] => 3.96,8.24,11.64,14.79,16.16,17.38,17.85,18.28,18.28

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, it's just for two. I based it on what was shown in your question, but I can update it to show how it could work for more.

Comment: Update, please. I'm sure it will be helpful in future.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already creating an array:

```
foreach ($result as $subArray) {
   $arrayNumbers[] = explode(",", $subArray->sum);
}

$first  = array_sum(array_column($arrayNumbers, 0));
$second = array_sum(array_column($arrayNumbers, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach ($result as $k => $subArray) {
    $arrayNumbers = explode(",",$subArray->sum);

    foreach ($arrayNumbers as $key => $value) {
        $sumArray[$key] = isset($sumArray[$key]) ? $sumArray[$key] : 0;
        $sumArray[$key] += $value;
    }
}
print_r($sumArray);
```